# Use telegram animated emojis in a bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to use the new custom animated emoji in a bot .the bot send the messages to a telegram channel . this service needs a premium telegram account for usual uses . but for bots ... i am not sure what to do . should i make the bot with a premium account to do the task or ... ?

Comment: if a feature is only available in premium, what makes you think a bot can use it for free?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki i dont want to use it as free !  i want to buy premium . the question was how to do it . and is it even possible to use animated emojis with bots ?

Comment: Did you found any way?